# How can I iterate over an RDD, using the same logic

Tags: scala, loops, rdd

I have data as below:

> 1,Bob,300
>   2,Tom,200
>   3,Sam,400

My expected output is:

> (1,1)
>   (2,2)
>   (3,3)
>   (1,Bob)
>   (2,Tom)
>   (3,Sam)
>   (1,300)
>   (2,200)
>   (3,400)

Iֿ'm a beginner in `scala`, and I require some help with the logic.

Below is what I have tried and got as output:

```
val data1 = file.map(x => {
  for(i <- 0 to 2) {
     for(j <- 0 to 2) {
       x(i) -> x(j)
     }
  }
})
```

This is what I am getting:

```
data1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Unit] = MapPartitionsRDD[26] at map at <console>:26
scala> data1.collect
res23: Array[Unit] = Array((), (), ())
```

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop that you used doesn't return a value, that's why you get `RDD[Unit]`.

Instead, you can use [Range](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/collection/immutable/Range.html) with [for comprehension](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/for-comprehensions.html), as follows:

```
val data1 = file.map(x => {
  for {
    i <- Range(0,3)
    j <- Range(0,3)
  } yield {
    x(i) -> x(j)
}})
```